# Clone only two branches in git

Tags: git, github

I have to clone a big repository from GitHub and I don't need to get all the branches but only the master and another. I know there is the command

```
git clone --single-branch
```

but of course this command only works with one branch.

Is there a good way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clone the first branch you use

```
git clone --single-branch --branch master URL myclone
```

To get the second branch, you must change the configuration of the new repostitory:

```
cd myclone
git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/foo:refs/remotes/origin/foo
```

This tells Git that it should also track branch `foo` of the remote repository. Now you do

```
git fetch
```

to get the other branch into your clone.